# How to Update RecyclerView With itemHolder

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to update all `RecyclerView` items using a Loop after clicking on the button. But all items set With Last loop value.

RecyclerView Adapter :

```
delete_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(dateSelected != null)
     {
         database.deleteObject(checkOut, classId, studentId, dateSelected);

        for (int i = 0 ; i < tableData.size() ; i++)
        {    
            int classId = tableData.get(i).getClassId();
            String studentId = tableData.get(i).getStudentId();
            int pCount = database.PositiveCounter(classId , studentId);

            itemHolder.studentPositive.setText(String.valueOf(pCount));
       }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

To update your RecyclerView, you need to update the list which contains the data first and then call notifydatasetchanged().

for eg. :

```
public void changeDataSet(List<Student> student) {
adapter.setList(student);
adapter.notifyDatasetChanged();
}
```

where setList will be part of your adapter and will look like this :

```
public void setList(List<Student> student) {
this.student = student;
}
```

You need to add a callback to your activity from adapter if the delete button is part of the itemView inside the holder.

Comment: my Problem is Positive Counter is Not in List<Student> So i cant use notiftDataSetChanged()

Answer (score 0):

In your activity, use below code in onClick on button

```
mAdapter.removeItem(position);
```

In Recycler View adapter class use add removeItem metod like below

```
public void removeItem(int position) {
    mList.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
}
```

Comment: my Problem is Positive Counter is Not in List<Student> So i cant use notiftDataSetChanged()

Comment: What do you mean by positive counter?